# knitr won't run Python commands

Tags: r, python-3.x, knitr

I have used `knitr` for a long time, usually in the R Studio environment.  Recently I installed Python (version 3.4.1) on my Windows machine, put it in the path, and tried out Yi Hui Xie's [sample document for Python](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/023-engine-python.Rmd). But the Python code chunks won't run.  From a chunk like this:

```
{r test-python, engine='python'}
x = 'hello, python world!'
print x
print x.split(' ')
```

I get an error message like this:

```
Warning: running command '"python"  -c "print '**Write** _something_ in `Markdown` from `Python`!'"' had status 1
running: "python"  -c "x = 'hello, python world!'
print x
print x.split(' ')"
  File "<string>", line 2
    print x
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm in Windows 7, running R 3.1.0, with RStudio Version 0.98.847 (beta preview version).  Interactive Python opens just fine from the command line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is that you've installed python3, but the syntax you're using is python2. The py2 -> py3 transition involved changes to the language itself -- in your example, `print` has changed from a syntax to a function. (So `print(x)` would work in your code above.)

The easiest option is to uninstall python3 and install the most recent Python 2.7 (currently [Python 2.7.6](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.6/)). Alternately, onward and upward -- use py3, which just involves possibly tweaking any existing examples you run into in `knitr`.